# Neatly print sp_help output similar to psql \d+

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I've just been granted access to a SQL Server data warehouse and I'm trying to get to grips with sqlcmd. Coming from a Postgres/psql background, I'm used to being able to quickly look up a table definition using short cuts like `\d+ [tablename]`. This produces a nice, single screen vertical summary of the table columns, datatypes and constraints. Something like this:
[image: \d+ example]

The equivalent I've found so far is `EXEC sp_help 'table_name'` but this prints an unreadable, multi-page mess. Is there a way to clean up this output? Is there a better TSQL command that will give a simple table summary?

Comment: Consider using SSMS or some other better graphical tool. `sqlcmd` isn't for the faint-hearted, it's more of an automated tool for batch queries and commands.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the command but you can query the catalog

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
where TABLE_SCHEMA='PUBLIC' and TABLE_NAME='EMP_BIO'
```